# Is there any set theory $T$ such that $T$ plus true arithmetic is complete with respect to statements in set theory?

Tags: set-theory, peano-arithmetic, metamathematics

Is there an [effective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#Effective_axiomatization) set theory $T$ such that $T + $[$TA$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_arithmetic) is consistient and complete. It should at least prove all theorems of [$ZF$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%.80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) true, so that it is a "standard" set theory. In particular, the axiom of infinity is required, since otherwise finite set theory would work, making the answer trivial. By complete, I mean every statement in the language of set theory is either provable or disprovable.

Another way of phrasing this question is what are a set of axioms of $T$ (which is either finite or such that its contents can be listed by a Turing machine), such that for any statement in the language of set theory, it can be decided by $T$ and statements in arithmetic (which are true of the standard integers).

If it fails, perhaps the requirement that $T$ be effective could be replaced by a requirement that $T$ is an [Arithmetical set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_set). Also, perhaps $TA$ could be replaced with some other consistent and complete theory of arithmetic (although this wouldn't be as useful as with $TA$).

The nice thing about such a theory is that, once $T$ is finalized, selecting new axioms would be metaphysically simpler, you could say. Instead of arguing over whether a given axiom is *actually* true of sets or not, the problem would be reduced to arguing about whether statements in arithmetic are true of integers or not (after $T$ has been selected).

tl;dr. Can you have a complete set theory, modulo arithmetic.

Comment: I'd guess that if $V=L+\forall\alpha(L_\alpha\not\models\mathsf{ZFC})$ doesn't do the trick, then perhaps nothing can do the trick. And I doubt it does the trick.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm not familiar with $L_\alpha$, but wouldn't any statement of the form $X \not \models Y$ be a statement of arithmetic (and therefore already be decided by $TA$)?

Comment: The theory would have to settle all questions about the halting problem relative to an oracle for TA. But it cannot do so correctly, since T+TA has the same complexity of TA itself, namely $0^{(\omega)}$. It follows that the theory T can have no model with the standard $\omega$.

Comment: But that doesn't seem yet enough to rule out such a theory....need a better argument.

Comment: @Joel I think a Rosser-style trick should be enough to finish your argument.

Comment: yes, I'm writing it up now, using TA-computably inseparable sets.

Comment: In particular, the idea of taking the numbers enumerated into A before they are enumerated into B amounts to a Rosser trick, confirming your idea. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There can be no such theory $T$, even if you weaken the requirement
to $T$ being merely arithmetically definable, rather than insisting it must be effective.

To see this, consider the theory T+TA, which should be consistent
and complete. Let $X$ be the set of Gödel codes of assertions in this theory, and let $A$ and $B$ be [$X$-computably inseparable sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_inseparable_sets),
which means that they are disjoint and with an oracle for $X$, we
can enumerate each of them, but there is no $X$-computable set
containing $A$ and disjoint from $B$. Fix specific programs for
enumerating $A$ and $B$ from an oracle for $X$.

Now, let $C$ be the set of numbers $n$ such that T+TA proves that
they are enumerated into $A$ before they are enumerated into $B$,
using the fixed programs and using what the theory thinks is TA. Because every member of $A$ is enumerated into $A$ by that program on account of only finitely much of the oracle, the theory T+TA will agree on that element being enumerated into $A$, and similarly with $B$. Thus, the set $C$ contains every actual element of $A$ and no actual element of $B$. But $C$ is computable from $X$, since we need only search for proofs from T+TA. Contradiction.

So there is no such theory T.

Comment: "Because every member of A is enumerated into A by that program on account of only finitely much of the oracle, the theory T+TA will agree on that element being enumerated into A" Could you expand on this?

Comment: The point is that we cannot be sure that the theory T+TA is sound, and so what it proves happens with the oracle might not be the same as what actually happens.  But we know that the elements of A are enumerated by the A-program before they are enumerated by the B-program, and this relies on only finitely much of the oracle, which is expressed as a single assertion of TA. So the theory will prove that every individual element of A is in C, and that the individual elements of B are definitely not in C.

Comment: I guess that King's program to complete set theory modulo arithmetic has failed. It was much shorter lived than Hilbert's program.

Comment: Is there a way to generalize these results. It seems that they could be generalized beyond arithmetic and set theory.